# How do I add keyboard bindings to carousel functionality? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, keyboard

You can see the implementation [here](http://fiwishop.com/feedback/feedback.html).

I would like to be able use the left and right arrows on my keyboard to cycle through the images. How do I do that, using jQuery or CSS?

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="slider-code">
        <a class="buttons prev" href="#"></a>
        <div class="viewport">
            <ul class="overview">           
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe-bw.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe-red.jpg" /></li>            
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe-dark.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe-red.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe-dark.jpg" /></li>           
            </ul>       
        </div>
        <a class="buttons next" href="#"></a>
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
#slider-code { 
    height: 125px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: auto;    /* top, right, bottom, left */ 
}

#slider-code .viewport { 
/*  margin-left: auto;    -- With this enabled, the arrows don't work.
    margin-right: auto;  */
    margin: 0 auto;    /* top, right, bottom, left */   
    width: 540px; 
    height: 125px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: relative;
    float: left;

}

#slider-code .viewport .overview img {
    border: 3px solid #f6f6f7;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

#slider-code .buttons { 
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto; /* top, right, bottom, left  */
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#slider-code .prev {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: transparent url('../images/left-arrow.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px; /* top, right, bottom, left */   
    position: relative;
/*  top: 190.5px;   */
}

#slider-code .next { 
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: transparent url('../images/right-arrow.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;  /* 30px 0 0 10px; */
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}

#slider-code .disable { 
     /* for IE */
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    /* for everything else */  
    opacity:0.4;
}

#slider-code .overview { 
    list-style: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
}


#slider-code .overview li { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 4px auto; /* top, right, bottom, left  */
    padding: 1px; 
    height: 121px; 
    border: 0px solid #dcdcdc;
    width: 236px;
}

.view_name {
    font-family: "Helvetica", serif;
    color: #f9f4c0;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    background: #1a1a1a;    
    padding: 1px 3px 1px 3px; /* top, right, bottom, left */        
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
}

ul.overview li { 
     position: relative; 
}
```

The requisite JS is:

```
var oImg, sliderCode, sliderViewPort, win_width;
    var oImg_height, oImg_width, oImg_ratio, tImg_width, tImg_height, sliderCode_w, sliderCode_h, ul_width;
    var rImg_width, rImg_height, view_new_w, view_new_h, li_w, rUl_width;

    function setUp(numImages) {
        oImg_height = oImg.height(); //size of original image height 
        oImg_width = oImg.width(); //size of original image width 
        oImg_ratio = oImg_height / oImg_width; //aspect ratio of original image 
        tImg_width = (win_width * 0.915) / num_of_images; // Target image width = (90% of the window) / 2 
        tImg_height = tImg_width * oImg_ratio; // Target image height, resized according to the original image ratio. 
        sliderCode_w = $('#slider-code').width();
        sliderCode_h = $('#slider-code').height();
        var ul_width = $('#slider-code .viewport ul').width();

        //  console.log("Original Image Height: ", oImg_height, " Original Image Width: ", oImg_width, " Original Image Aspect Ratio: ", oImg_ratio, " Slider Code Width: ", sliderCode_w, " Slider Code Height: ", sliderCode_h, " Window Width: ", win_width, " UL Width: ", ul_width, " Target Image Width: ", tImg_width, " Target Image Height: ", tImg_height); 

        sliderCode = $('#slider-code .viewport .overview img:lt(26)').css({ 'width': tImg_width, 'height': tImg_height });   //resizes the images

        rImg_width = sliderCode.width(); // size of resized image width  
        rImg_height = sliderCode.height(); // size of resized image width 

        $('#slider-code .next').css({ 'top': rImg_height / 2 }); //This needs to be resolved for various size windows 
        $('#slider-code .prev').css({ 'top': rImg_height / 2 });
        $('#slider-code').css({ 'width': '100%', 'height': rImg_height + 10 }); //to accomodate borders, extra padding was added to heights. To make it truly dynamic, a variable (as a percentage) of the width of the window, could be used to be added to the height 
        $('#slider-code .viewport').css({ 'width': win_width * 0.94, 'height': rImg_height + 10 });
        $('#slider-code .overview li').css({ 'width': rImg_width + 10 }); 
        $('#edit-image-nav img').css({ 'width' : '42px', 'height' : '30px', 'display' : 'block' });  //This was done because without it, something else is resizing the images to a large size. I was not able to trace it, but in a re-factor, I should trace what is resizing it and remove that, then remove this.
        //$('#slider-code .overview li img:not("#edit-image-nav")').css({ 'width': rImg_width + 10 }); 
        view_new_w = sliderViewPort.width();
        view_new_h = sliderViewPort.height();
        li_w = $('#slider-code .overview li').width();
        rUl_width = $('#slider-code .viewport ul').width();

        //  console.log("Viewport New Width: ", view_new_w, view_new_h, " List Item Width: ", li_w, " Resized Image Width: ", rImg_width, " Resized Image Height: ", rImg_height, " Resized UL Width: ", rUl_width); 

        $('#slider-code').tinycarousel({ controls: true, animation: true, display: 1 });

    }

$(window).load(function() {

 //Cache Some Common Elements
        oImg = $('#slider-code .viewport .overview img:eq(1)');
        sliderViewPort = $('#slider-code .viewport');

        // --------------------------- Begin Comparison Code --------------------------------------------------------        
        win_width = $(window).width();
        num_of_images = 2; //The number of images expected in view (2 for 2-up, 3 for 3-up, etc.) The default value is 2. 

        $("#viewbar img").click(function(e) {
            num_of_images = parseInt($(this).attr("data-id"), 10); // This accepts the integer associated with the navbar.           
            $('#viewname').text(num_of_images + '-up');

            setUp(num_of_images);

            e.preventDefault();
        });

        //Default set up
        setUp(num_of_images);

        // --------------- End Comparison Code -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

})
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown( function(eventObject) {
     if(eventObject.which==37) {//left arrow
        $('#slider-code .prev').click();//emulates click on prev button 
     } else if(eventObject.which==39) {//right arrow
        $('#slider-code .next').click();//emulates click on next button
     }
} );
```

You may replace $(document) with $('.viewport'), but then <div class="viewport"> must be in focus then keypress occures

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 jQuery keyboard options, [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/), [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) and [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) depending on what you want. you could do something like this.

```
$('.viewport').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37){ //left arrow clicked
        //do something
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39){//right arrow clicked
        //do something else
    }
});
```